# How to plot all files in one folder in python?

Tags: python, numpy

Following to this answer [How to plot 10 traces in same figure with different color in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132349/how-to-plot-10-traces-in-same-figure-with-different-color-in-python/42136046#42136046)
I need to plot many files with the extension .numpy which are saved in my folder test

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import os, sys

#Read in list of files. You might want to look into os.listdir()

path='/home/user/Desktop/test'
traces= os.listdir( path )

# Create figure 
fig=plt.figure()
fig.show()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

# Grab colormap
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('jet')

# Loop through traces and plot them
for j,trace in enumerate(traces):

    # Load file
    dataArray= np.load(trace)

    # Grab color
    c=cmap(float(j)/len(traces))

    # Plot
    ax.plot(dataArray.T,color=c)

plt.show()
```

But I have this error:

```
dataArray= np.load(trace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 370, in load
    fid = open(file, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'trace14.npy'
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this error because likely you are running the script from a directory other than `'/home/user/Desktop/test'`. You can try moving the script to `'/home/user/Desktop/test'` and running it again, or use `os.path.join` to create an absolute path to the file. i.e.:

```
for j,trace in enumerate(traces):

    filepath = os.path.join(path, trace)
    # Load file
    dataArray= np.load(filepath)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the path of file, it is directly looking for `trace14.py` can you add path to it, which would look like:

```
dataArray = np.load(path+trace)
```

and modify path to:

```
path = "/home/user/Desktop/test/"
```

Comment: I change it like this: dataArray= os.listdir(path)
traces = np.load(path+dataArray), but i still have the same problem.

Comment: can you paste the error here ? also did you change the path to have an extra '/' at the end

Comment: `dataArray` is the array of the path so it wouldn't work. Please try `np.load(path+trace)`